# “Failed to fetch”

Tags: apt, update-manager

how to fix it?

```
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/mefrio-g/plymouthmanager/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: which command did you executed which resulted with the output in the question? please [edit] your question with this info

Answer (score 2):

Checking [this address](http://ppa.launchpad.net/mefrio-g/plymouthmanager/ubuntu/dists/) you can find out that this package is not available for Xenial.
The PPA has not been updated since 2011.
I recommend you not to use outdated packages.

You can [use command line to change plymouth themes](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2340103).